# How to record video with exact frames timestamp in c++

Tags: c++, opencv, camera, lossless-compression, video-compression

I would like to record frames from a camera in c++. The camera frame-rate is not constant, and I need to store each image with its timestamp (I am using OS clock, and storing the image milliseconds precision). I have already stored the captured images as a sequence of images files but the images stored independently (as .png) are too heavy (because I am working with long sequences and they are a lot). So, I would like to take advantage of the similarity between consecutive images (as video compression techniques) and create a lossless video that exploits this fact. Then, I would like to use this video to extract the images individually conserving the timestamp.

In other words, I am only using the video format to compress the image sequence (without lose information) but I need to keep track of the exact timestamp when the images were captured.

So my question is:
**How can I record the streaming of the camera in a video using the exact timestamp of each frame in a lossless format?**

I have been trying with OpenCV library, in particular with the [VideoWriter](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4.3/dd/d9e/classcv_1_1VideoWriter.html) class. However the VideoWriter interface does not provide any method that takes the frame and timestamp as input.

Another option that I have, is to store, along with the video recorded, the timestamp of each frame in a separately txt file. Then, I could use the timestamp to retrieve the frames from the video. However, I am not sure if I would retrieve the exact frame, this is without any information interpolation.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Maybe these will help: [What is a good lossless video codec](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/768999/what-is-a-good-lossless-video-codec), [What is the best lossless video compression technique](https://www.quora.com/What-is-the-best-lossless-video-compression-technique-with-the-best-compression-ratio)

Comment: I am looking to keep the exact timestamp of each frame in the video, not only the video compression settings. I am setting the timestamp with the OS clock.

Comment: I basically have the same feature request as you. I'm still not sure what kind of library can do this.

Answer (score 1):

Does the format have to be portable?

If not, here's an idea: Interleave the pixels from a bunch of pictures (the number can vary over time depending on how big the changes are).

So, a chunk with N pictures in your file will contain:

```
N: the number of pictures in the chunk
timestamp 1: from picture 1
timestamp 2: from picture 2
...
timestamp N: from picture N
pixel 1: from picture 1, pixel 0,0
pixel 2: from picture 2, pixel 0,0
...
pixel N: from picture N, pixel 0,0
pixel N+1: from picture 1, pixel 0,1
pixel N+2: from picture 2, pixel 0,1
...
pixel N*X*Y: from picture N, pixel X-1,Y-1
```

Then use a lossless compression library to compress the chunk (now containing a 3D image) and get on with the next chunk.

Perhaps there are already wavelet/fft libraries capable of something similar.

Comment: This looks like more like a post-processing method. I would like to create the video as soon a new frame arrives. The important thing here is not the compression, the important issue here is to store the exact timestamp in the video. The timestamp is given by the OS in this case.

Comment: In that case, won't compression on file system-level suffice?

Comment: no, because I need to do it on the fly. One option that I have is too record the frames as a video and save in a separate txt file the timestamp for each stored frame in the video but I do not like this option too much

Comment: If you use filesystem compression you will get each frame compressed and stored (with its timestamp) on the fly.

If you need need better compression, use a lossless 2D image compressor.

If that doesn't compress enough, you need a chunk of frames before you can make use of any similarities between the frames by using a lossless 3D image compressor, so on the fly becomes "with only a chunk of frames delay", right?

Comment: What do you mean with "use filesystem compression" to store the images as png (and not like a video)? I have already done that and it is too heavy.

Comment: Yes, that was my first option. Since you use png I guess the pictures are already compressed and then the filesystem compression won't help. That leaves you with option three and I can't see how that can be done without a chunk of frames delay.

Comment: I do not know exactly the meaning of "lossless 3D image compressor", does it mean compress the sequence of images taking their similarity, right? Do you know any lossless 3D image compressor software or c++ library?

Comment: Yes, that's what I meant. I don't know of any free libraries unfortunately but there are many papers written on the topic, mostly for compressing 3D images in medical applications.